# Is there a better way to jump to transformed sections on a page?

Tags: javascript, scroll, navigation, single-page-application

I have been working on a single-page website in Webflow that uses some animations to create a parallax effect while scrolling. It looks great, however this causes any links directly targeting these sections in the navigation to scroll to that section while it is still behind another.

To counteract this, I wrote code that gathers the heights of the elements and applies that as a top value for a hidden div element that the link targets instead. It seems to work on larger screen sizes, but as the screen's width shrinks and section heights lengthen from the content wrapping, it becomes less and less accurate.

This is the javascript I wrote:

```
//Declare height variables
var navHeight = document.getElementById("nav").offsetHeight;
var sectionPad = 80;
  
var heroHeight = document.getElementById("hero-section").scrollHeight;
var problemHeight = document.getElementById("problem-section").scrollHeight;
var solutionHeight = document.getElementById("solution-section").scrollHeight;
var planHeight = document.getElementById("plan-section").scrollHeight;
var teamHeight = document.getElementById("team-section").scrollHeight;
var contactHeight = document.getElementById("contact-section").scrollHeight;
  
//Declare distance variables
var problemDis = navHeight + heroHeight + 80;
var solutionDis = navHeight + heroHeight + problemHeight;
var teamDis = navHeight + heroHeight + problemHeight + solutionHeight + planHeight;
var contactDis = navHeight + heroHeight + problemHeight + solutionHeight + planHeight + teamHeight;
//alert(Math.round(problemDis));
  
//Set anchor heights
document.getElementById("problem").style.top = problemDis+"px";
document.getElementById("solution").style.top = solutionDis+"px";
document.getElementById("team").style.top = teamDis+"px";
document.getElementById("contact").style.top = contactDis+"px";
```

I tried a couple other ways of getting element height like `offsetHeight` and `clientHeight` but `scrollHeight` has gotten me the closest.